# Skip a real time update

Tags: upgrade

I ran the following command to upgrade: `sudo apt-get install upgrade`. For some reason, the upgrade of the package google-chrome-stable is not going as expected - it downloads the 40MB package but it freezes mid way and starts all over again from 0kb (for google-chrome-stable only). I assume that it has finished downloading other packages but it cannot proceed to install them since download of a package is still pending.

How do I skip this package so that it can proceed with the installation and upgrade of other packages which have been downloaded completely.

Keep in mind that the upgrade is currently running so removing the repository from ubuntu software center will be for future upgrades - I need a solution for an upgrade happening right now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but always before upgrading I run `sudo apt-get update` to update the repositories, you can also add && to run them at the same time.

Moving on a fresh install of kubuntu coming from windows. I found chrome to be insanly unstable as in crash 5 times in a row after loading up.

With that said there is a good remedy out there in the form of chromium, which the linux community perfers over chrome. I logged into my google account sync everything, most of my plugins and almost all my information was transferred. I think one or two plugins were left, but that might have been because they were on my windows machine and didn't sync them.